# App ID with Identifier is not available

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to xcode, my xcode shows:

```
No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier “com.domainName.AppName” were found.

Xcode can attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles.
```

After I click on "fix issue" button, then I receive the message:

```
App ID with Identifier 'com.domainName.AppName' is not available
```

It is theoretical impossible to have someone else having the same App ID as I doubt no one should have same domainName as mine. How could I find which account and who is having that App ID?

Comment: you should have this app id against any of your developer account logged in xcode and a valid provisional profile against certificate (with that account ) should be installed on your system .

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to create the provisioning certificate and still wants to run the app on the device then you must have to add the apple account in `xcode` and then you must do the following steps:[image: Team Selection]

Just select the team name which you had added the account and then change the `Code Signing Identity` [image: Code Signing Identity]

Answer (score 0):

go to xcode - > preferences  -> accounts - >select apple ids - >(select ur agent account if any) and click on view details - >select ur signing identity and click download all

Answer (score 0):

It is because you haven't created an app id in apple developer website or you have't added right account into Xcode Accounts.

So first, go to developer site and check if you need to add App Id `com.domainName.AppName`. 
Second, go to add your account into Xcode accounts. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts and click plus button in the bottom left to add account if you haven't yet.

After that try to press fix issue again and it should work